# Can we set IFS to a range of numbers?

Tags: bash, ifs

I know I could have the user use a common IFS like space, comma, etc., but I would like to be able to have the user simply input their chemical formula (i.e., H2O) and split this into elements and their numbers. For example, if Na2V2O5 is their input, I want to be able to store this information as follows:

Element1: Na     Numberofatoms: 2

Element2: V      Numberofatoms: 2

Element3: O      Numberofatoms: 5

Is it possible to separate things by number or perhaps even looking for capital letters? This is for a bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
$ IFS=1234567890 read -a atoms <<< "Na2V2O5"
$ declare -p atoms
declare -a atoms=([0]="Na" [1]="V" [2]="O")
```

However, the numbers themselves are not retained; field splitters are simply discarded.

A word of advice: don't try to write parsers in shell.

Comment: What would happen if the number was two digits? Would it just be best to have the user input with another common IFS?

Comment: With two digits, you'll get an empty field. `IFS` is only meant for *very* simple parsing. The fact that multiple spaces are treated as a single delimiter is a special case: "Any  character  in IFS that is not IFS whitespace,
       along with any adjacent IFS whitespace characters, delimits a field."

Comment: I ended up switching to have the user input their formula such as Na:2,V:2,O:5. Not the simplest input in the world, but it works. Thanks again.